# nested collision starling as3

Tags: actionscript-3, collision, intersect

I am using starling and tweenMax frameworks in my project.
The trouble I am running into is this:

For the purpose of animating along different paths, I am using tweenmax.

There is one _leaderEnemy that animates along a path and I am pushing several other _shooterEnemy (they are of the same class) into it.

```
public function createEnemies(enemyNo:int, path:Array, offset:int):void
{
    for(var i:uint=1;i<=enemyNo;i++){
        if (i==1){
            _leaderCount++;
            _leaderEnemy = new ShooterEnemy();
            _leaderEnemy.x=600;
            _leaderEnemy.y=300;
            _leaderEnemy.name="_shooterEnemy"+_leaderCount;
            this.addChild(_leaderEnemy);
            leaderEnemyArray.push(_leaderEnemy);
        }
        else
        {
            _leaderCount++;
            _shooterEnemy= new ShooterEnemy();
            _shooterEnemy.x=0;
            _shooterEnemy.y=(offset*(i-1));
            _shooterEnemy.name="_shooterEnemy"+_leaderCount;
            trace("no: "+_shooterEnemy.name);
            leaderEnemyArray.push(_shooterEnemy);
            _leaderEnemy.addChild(_shooterEnemy);
        }
    }
```

Now I want to check for collision using starling between each of the _leaderEnemy and the _shooterEnemy inside it with _shooterHero.

Running this array successfully checks collision with the whole group i.e. _leaderEnemy but not the individual ones inside it.

Technically, I should be able to do this just by:

```
var Track:Object;
for(var i:uint=0;i<leaderEnemyArray.length;i++) {
    Track=leaderEnemyArray[i];      
    if (Track.bounds.intersects(_shooterHero.bounds)){
        Track.rotation=deg2rad(70);             
    }
}
```

It may be something stupid I am doing. But I have not been able to solve this.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Some other questions I have:

1. Can I check for collision with _shooterHero from inside the _shooterEnemy's class?

I have tried:

```
if (this.bounds.intersects(stage.getChildByName("_hero"))){
}
```

although it did not work.

1. Can I check for collision of one Enemy with everything on stage, so I can assign individual functions for his each contact?
   For example: hit with hero: die; hit with another enemy: turn around

If you need more info, I will be happy to provide it.

Thank You.

Comment: Try using `for each ... in` loops.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I check for collision of one Enemy with everything on stage, so I can assign individual functions for his each contact? For example: hit with hero: die; hit with another enemy: turn around

Of course you can. You should! This is approximatively how collision engines works.

> Running this array successfully checks collision with the whole group i.e. _leaderEnemy but not the individual ones inside it.

Nope. It won't work. Because the bounds property use the parent coordinates.
Meaning you can intersect each child display (of same container) with each other.
But you shouldn't intersect a child display of A with a child display of B.

Except if you convert every bounds coordinates (which are local) to global.

[http://doc.starling-framework.org/core/starling/display/DisplayObject.html#localToGlobal()](http://doc.starling-framework.org/core/starling/display/DisplayObject.html#localToGlobal%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Using Track.bounds.intersects is one way of checking collosions. Another would be to use hitTest method of [starling.displayDisplayObject](http://doc.starling-framework.org/core/starling/display/DisplayObject.html)

You could also check the distance of your hero and other enemies calculated by a pythagorean theorem type calculation.

Are you checking enemies against each other? If you have many enemies you might want to look into "flocking" algorithms. Keith Petes covers this subject nicely in his book Advanced Actionscript Animation.